# Creating a Lunar Calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar

I am creating a lunar calendar and I am wondering if it is possible to implement a function in JavaScript that would allow me to change the months and days around on the calendar. If so, how would something like that look? The easy solution is to just create 12 html files (one for each month) but is that an acceptable way of doing it? Here is how my code looks for just one month: https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/peLtbxp9/2/ All of the month names are stored in this function here:

```
 function writeIslamicDate(adjustment) {
    var wdNames = new Array("Ahad","Ithnin","Thulatha","Arbaa","Khams","Jumuah","Sabt");
    var iMonthNames = new Array("Muharram","Safar","Rabi'ul Awwal","Rabi'ul Akhir",
       "Jumadal Ula","Jumadal Akhira","Rajab","Sha'ban",
       "Ramadan","Shawwal","Dhul Qa'ada","Dhul Hijja");
    var iDate = kuwaiticalendar(adjustment);
    var outputIslamicDate = wdNames[iDate[4]] + ", " 
       + iDate[5] + " " + iMonthNames[iDate[6]] + " " + iDate[7] + " AH";
 return outputIslamicDate;
}
```

Comment: Have you find any solution @MahmudAdam? I too have to display lunar calendar using JavaScript.